# MIDI out over USB

Tags: python, usb, bash, midi

I'm trying to build a MIDI controller using a Raspberry Pi Zero. I have all the hardware and code to process the (analog) input signals, but I can't figure out how to send the MIDI data over USB. I plugged the Pi into a PC running Ableton, but when I did an `lsusb` query in bash on the Pi the PC didn't appear. I realize it's a bit unconventional to run a USB cable between two computers, but is there any way to send the data through? (Preferably using only bash and python)

Comment: Use [g_midi](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pi+zero%22+g_midi).